# Kubuntu 16.04 Multiple monitor issue (Kubuntu logo displayed instead)

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors

Originally, I had two Radeon HD 7950s each connected to two monitors and working together to make four monitors as one desktop just fine.

After the computer lost power these was an issue with the swap partition and two of the monitors (from one gpu) displayed a window asking for a password to unlock the swap. I assumed the swap was not unmounted correctly due to the loss of power and remapped the swap partition to the correct one fixing the issue.

However now, the monitors/gpu that displayed the swap password prompt no longer work and instead display only the kubuntu logo. They are unaccessible from any system settings or command line monitor listing. I have tried numerous reboots and unplug/replug combinations to no avail. Additionally I am certain it is not caused by a hardware issue because I dualboot with Windows 10 and all monitors work correctly in this OS.

My guess is that there was configuration somehow overwritten when Kubuntu saw fit to replace two of the screens with a prompt for a swap password. However, I am not sure of this and don't know how to undo what was done. What can be done about this? Also, I find it very unlikely but is it possible that the swap space has not be reconfigured correctly and this is causing the issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a 3 monitor setup and after a power loss the 3rd monitor doesn't load properly, it's stuck on Kubuntu logo. In Windows it works fine.

Comment: run `xrandr` lets see if it sees the second monitor...